# What do I need in my web.config to make wordpress work?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I have a custom website developed in C# ASP.NET.  I installed Wordpress in a separate folder as a sub domain.  I keep getting 404 page can not be displayed.  What do I need to put in my web.config file to allow this site to come up?

Comment: There is only one web.config file by the way in the root directory.

Comment: Check whether PHP installed in your server?

Comment: This [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-wordpress-on-iis) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it was.  I needed to change the pipeline from integrated to classic for some reason.